# Flow of python decorator functions

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I'm trying to understand the following example I found explaining `decorators`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def get_text(name):
   return "lorem ipsum, {0} dolor sit amet".format(name)

def p_decorate(func):
    def func_wrapper(name):
        return "<p>{0}</p>".format(func(name))
    #return "1"
     return func_wrapper


get_text = p_decorate(get_text)

print get_text("John")
```

The output of this is:

```
<p>lorem ipsum, John dolor sit amet</p>
```

I decided to try and change this function up and commented out `return func_wrapper` and replaced it with `return "1"`.

When I do this, I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I have 2 questions regarding this:

1. When the line

   ```
   print get_text("John")
   ```

   is executed, is

   ```
   def func_wrapper(name):
   ```

   initialised with `"John"`? What is the sequence of events after this line is run?
2. Why am I getting this error, because in the end, isn't a `string` ultimately being returned anyway?

If anyone could explain the flow of events with this code, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You called the decorator here:

```
get_text = p_decorate(get_text)
```

Normally, a decorator replaces a function with another callable (another function, for example), or returns the original function but having registered information about it.

But by changing the return value of `p_decorate()` to `"1"` rather than the function wrapper, you 'broke' `get_text` as that is no longer a function now. You cannot call a string object like you could call a string.

Before, `p_decorate()` returned the `func_wrapper()` function object, so `get_text` was rebound to point to that function. Calling `get_text('John')` really called that nested function. `func_wrapper()` is then indeed called with `'John'` as the argument, yes. Functions are after all just objects, you can assign those objects to any valid Python name you like.

When `func_wrapper()` is called, it in turn calls `func()`, which was the argument to `p_decorate()`. Again, functions are *just objects*, so having called `p_decorate(get_text)`, `func` ends up still bound to the original `get_text` function object. Calling `func()` calls that original function.

You can see the full flow of the calls in [Python Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def+get_text%28name%29%3A%0A+++return+%22lorem+ipsum,+%7B0%7D+dolor+sit+amet%22.format%28name%29%0A%0Adef+p_decorate%28func%29%3A%0A++++def+func_wrapper%28name%29%3A%0A++++++++return+%22%3Cp%3E%7B0%7D%3C/p%3E%22.format%28func%28name%29%29%0A++++return+func_wrapper%0A%0A%0Aget_text+%3D+p_decorate%28get_text%29%0A%0Aprint+get_text%28%22John%22%29%0A&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=14).

Comment: Thank you Martijn for that explanation. `Python Tutor` was quite helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement.

You  use nested functions when you want to pass args inside decorator:

```
def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('My args:', *args, **kwargs)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

So you decorate:

```
def my_function(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
my_function = decorator(my_function)
```